# Monotouch: Changing the Hue of an image, not just Saturation

Tags: ios, image-processing, xamarin.ios, uiimage, hue

I have the following `MonoTouch` code which can change the `Saturation` , but I am trying to also change the `Hue`.

```
float hue = 0;
float saturation = 1;

if (colorCtrls == null)
    colorCtrls = new CIColorControls() { 
                 Image = CIImage.FromCGImage (originalImage.CGImage) };
else
    colorCtrls.Image = CIImage.FromCGImage(originalImage.CGImage);

colorCtrls.Saturation = saturation; 

var output = colorCtrls.OutputImage;
var context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
var result = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);

return UIImage.FromImage(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of a different filter so you'll need to use [`CIHueAdjust`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIHueAdjust) instead of `CIColorControls` to control the hue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing to add Hue:

```
        var hueAdjust = new CIHueAdjust() {
            Image = CIImage.FromCGImage(originalImage.CGImage),
            Angle = hue // Default is 0
        };
        var output = hueAdjust.OutputImage;
        var context = CIContext.FromOptions(null);
        var cgimage = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);
        return UIImage.FromImage(cgimage);
```

However, this  does not work on Retina devices, the image returned is scaled incorrectly.

Comment: Miguel made a nice video (on youtube) on using CoreImage with MonoTouch (including chaining filters). http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yb2pi3tDb3c

Comment: This example does not work on Retina devices, the image returned is scaled incorrectly.

Comment: Please clarify: when you say "does not work on Retina devices" do you just mean "when using UINavigationController.Appearance.SetBackgroundImage" (as per SO #11805628)? Generally I believe this code does indeed work when assigning the UIImage to a UIImageView which has its Bounds correctly set.

Comment: For Retina devices try return new UIImage(cgimage, 2f, UIImageOrientation.Up);