# MonoTouch: CIContext in FinishedLaunching seems to crash app?

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, core-image

I am changing the Hue of images in FinishedLaunching () as part of my use of the Appearance settings. When I attempt to get the CIContext, the app is toren down without any crash information.

Here's the code:

```
        var hueAdjust = new CIHueAdjust() {
            Image = CIImage.FromCGImage(originalImage.CGImage),
            Angle = hue * (float)Math.PI / 180f // angles to radians
        };

        var output = hueAdjust.OutputImage;

        UIImage retVal = null;

        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.Size, false, 0);
        using (var c = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ())
        {
            //****This next line causes the crash*******
            var context = CIContext.FromContext(c);
            var cgimage = context.CreateCGImage(output, output.Extent);
            retVal = UIImage.FromImage(cgimage);
        }
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        return retVal;
```

I have tested setting this at various times of the app lifecycle, but it appears to always instantly get toren down.

Comment: this is a wild stab in the dark, but does refactoring to NOT use the using statement have any impact?  Ideally it shouldn't, but it might be worth a try

Comment: Hi Jason, I gave that a go, but it still crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for filling the [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=6401). The crash was due to an endless recursion in [FromContext](https://github.com/mono/maccore/commit/ab15a52c3d7c1206eb041d56985cdb38b03aa70a#L0L58). However this won't solve your [original problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11805628/220643) since the API that was exposed does not exists in iOS (it's OSX specific).

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly when you say I called an OSX API in iOS via MonoTouch?

Comment: Yes. A few methods *leaked* from monomac into MonoTouch (and are currently shown by MonoDevelop code completion since they are public). We have automated tests to catch such cases, but these were somehow missed (I'll be looking into this asap).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand what you're trying to do, but here is some code to change the hue of an image:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762982/1560797

I guess the method you use is a bug in Monotouch. I've tried it in a demo application myself, and it's generating a crash report on my device. (I'm not really familiar in reading the crash logs, so don't know exactly what's happening)
Please report it at xamarin